# How can I flatten every n rows in matrix using Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I can easily flatten an entire matrix into one row using `reshape(M,1,[])`. However, this time I want to flatten every n rows into one row. Thus, if we start with 100 rows and n=10, we will end up with 10 rows.

e.g.

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
10 11 12
```

with n=2 changes into

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
7 8 9 10 11 12
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose your original matrix is `m`, then:

```
reshape(m',[6 2])'
```

produces the required output. I'll leave it to you to generalise to other cases; comment or post again if that causes you problems.

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
reshape(M',l/n,n)'
```

Where n is what you've defined and l is the total elements in M.

EDIT: Made it one-liner